# f-test whether any predictors are significant

Tags: regression

In the R software I use the F-test give by linear regression output tests whether any of the predictors other than the intercept is nonzero. I want to test whether any predictor, including the intercept, is non-zero. In other words, whether the depending variable is just mean zero gaussian noise. I think I can do this by using a variant of the usual f-statistic. In the denominator I would put the residual variance divided by its degrees of freedom, $\sum_i\epsilon_i^2 / (n-p)$. In the numerator I would subtract the regression residuals, $(\sum_i y_i^2 - \sum_i \epsilon_i^2)/p$ with df=p. Which should be distributed as $F$ with parameters $p,n-p$. My question is whether this procedure method is correct. Also whether this p-value actually boils down to some other quantity already reported in the regression output that I'm not connecting it to.

Comment: I believer the usual test of the whole model would be what you want. This is the F typically given at the bottom of common regression-table output

Comment: @Glen_b I believe that may be testing whether any of the design covariates (other than the intercept) has 0 coefficient, at least in R. E.g. if I regress rnorm(1e4,mean=5) against rnorm(1e4), R returns a highly significant intercept but the F-test at the bottom is not at all significant. Because the intercept is 0.

Comment: I get it, sorry I missed the point before. But you mean the slope is 0 at the end there.  If you want the intercept in the test as well as all the predictors, you compare a completely null model to the full model: `y=rnorm(1000,5,1); 
x=rnorm(1000); 
mnull=lm(y~0); 
mfull=lm(y~x); 
anova(mnull,mfull)`

Comment: indeed compare these two anova tables: `set.seed(124241); y=rnorm(100,2,1);  x=rnorm(100);  mnull=lm(y~0);  mint=lm(y~1); mfull=lm(y~x);  anova(mnull,mint,mfull); anova(mnull,mfull)` and see that the first shows tests for intercept alone and slope given there's an intercept, while the second combines their SS and DF

Comment: The F-test is a model comparison of your model to a model with some parameters omitted. While I am not sure how to get the degrees of freedom or if the null distribution would be F, the same idea should apply. // It is strange to test if the intercept is zero, too. Could this be an XY problem where you want to do such a test to solve the real problem you’re hoping to solve?

Comment: @Glen_b Perfect, thank you. By comparison with the aov output I see I was using the wrong denominator above, which I'll update. Obviously, if you put this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the intercept in the test as well as all the predictors, you compare a completely null model to the full model:

```
y <- rnorm(1000,5,1)
x <- rnorm(1000)  
mnull <- lm(y~0)
mfull <- lm(y~x)
anova(mnull,mfull) 

Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: y ~ 0
Model 2: y ~ x
  Res.Df     RSS Df Sum of Sq     F    Pr(>F)    
1   1000 26099.8                                 
2    998   921.8  2     25178 13630 < 2.2e-16 ***
```

Indeed compare these two ANOVA tables:

```
set.seed(124241)
y <- rnorm(100,2,1)
x <- rnorm(100)
mnull <- lm(y~0)
mint <- lm(y~1)
mfull <- lm(y~x)
anova(mnull,mint,mfull)
anova(mnull,mfull)
```

and see that the first shows tests for intercept alone and slope given there's an intercept,

```
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: y ~ 0
Model 2: y ~ 1
Model 3: y ~ x
  Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq        F Pr(>F)    
1    100 532.57                                 
2     99 102.24  1    430.33 414.2516 <2e-16 ***
3     98 101.80  1      0.44   0.4208 0.5181
```

while the second combines their SS and DF:

```
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: y ~ 0
Model 2: y ~ x
  Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F    Pr(>F)    
1    100 532.57                                  
2     98 101.80  2    430.76 207.34 < 2.2e-16 ***
```